# Looking for any Jetson Nano DockerHub example that uses the GPU

Tags: docker, gpu, nvidia-jetson

I'm getting started with my Jetson Nano and I'm looking for an example that I can launch by running `docker run xxx` where xxx is some image at DockerHub that uses the GPU.

I assume I'll have to pass in some --device flags, but is there even any kind of "hello world"-style sample ready to go that uses the GPU from docker?

I'm hoping to just demonstrate that you can access the GPU from a docker container on the Jetson Nano.  Mostly to make sure that my configuration is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvidia Jetpack 4.2.1 enabled easy Docker with GPU on Jetson Nano.

See here for detailed instruction on how to get Docker and Kubernetes running on Jetson Nano with GPU:

https://medium.com/jit-team/building-a-gpu-enabled-kubernets-cluster-for-machine-learning-with-nvidia-jetson-nano-7b67de74172a

It uses a simple Docker Hub hosted image for TensorFlow:

Answer (score 1):

You're not alone in wanting that, but you cannot do it at the moment. The NVIDIA Nano team are aware of the need, and the feature is expected later this year.

See https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1050809/jetson-nano/docker-image-to-see-if-cuda-is-working-in-container-on-jetson-nano-/

At present you can run a docker container with TensorFlow or PyTorch installed. but it will only use the CPU, not the GPU.